# Join statement for multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-1.4, propel

This is something that really bugs me, but first the code, then the question:

```
<?php
 public static function retrievePagerByTagArray($page, $limit, $tags) {

    $criteria = new Criteria();

    $criteria->addJoin(self::MASTER_ID, MasterPeer::MASTER_ID);

    foreach($tags as $tag) {
      $criteria->addOr(MasterHasTagPeer::TAG_ID, $tag->getPrimaryKey());
    }

    $criteria->add(self::IS_ACTIVE, 1);
    $criteria->addDescendingOrderByColumn(self::MASTER_ID);
    $pager = new sfPropelPager('Master');

    $pager->setCriteria($criteria);
    $pager->setPage($page);
    $pager->setMaxPerPage($limit);
    $pager->init();
    return $pager;
  }
```

What i want to do is this:

my tags are made with get parameters so tags come like http://example.com?filter=tag1%7tag2 etc... i convert those tags to their corresponding tagid and want to filter my results to just the stuff that has those too parameters meaning:

master_has_tag is  an n:m-table only storing the ids.

I know that the `$criteria->addOr(MasterHasTagPeer::TAG_ID, $tag->getPrimaryKey());` is not what im looking for since this is giving me all entries containing atleast one of the filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to build a query with `WHERE tag_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4...)`. However, I'm not familiar with Symony or Propel so you will need to find the corresponding method.

If `$tags` is an array of ids you can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) to combine the ids into a comma-separated string.

```
$tag_ids = implode(',', $tags);
```

If `$tags` is an array of objects then you can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) to make the same thing.

```
// create an array of tag ids
$tags = array_map(function($tag) {
  return $tag->getPrimaryKey();
}, $tags);

// create a comma-separated string of ids
$tag_ids = implode(',', $tags);
```

Comment: well... i try to fiddle arround a bit, i keep you updated since i know there is a "in" function in propel

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a MasterQuery with multiple inner joins since you're looking for Masters which have n tags:

```
$q = MasterQuery::create();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  $q->useMasterHasTagQuery('Tag'.$tag->getId(), 'inner join')
    ->filterByTagId($tag->getId())
  ->endUse()
}
$masters = $q->find();
```

Sort of.

Comment: I think it should; change last line, instead of $q->find(), use $q as criteria for the pager.

Comment: im trying that when i get back from work and keep you updated

Comment: Of course Propel has Criteria::IN, but that's not what you are looking for i think: $c->add(<fieldPeer>, array(cond1, cond2), Criteria::IN) is the same as "cond1 OR cond2". You don't want ORs, or do you?

Comment: nope no ORs, since or is delivering all masters containing atleast 1 of the tags but i want only the masters with all tags